# WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 installation issue - CARBON_HOME is set incorrectly or CARBON could not be located. Please set CARBON_HOME

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to install `WSO2 APIM 4.1.0` in `Windows 11` Enterprise Edition.

- Downloaded zip Achieve from [wso2 site](https://wso2.com/api-manager/#)
- `JAVA_HOME` already set as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291`
- Started WSO2 API-M by navigating to the `C:\Development_Avecto\WSO2APImServer\ORG\org_wso2am\wso2am-4.1.0\bin` and executed `api-manager.bat --run`

after executing above command below ERROR shown

`CARBON_HOME is set incorrectly or CARBON could not be located. Please set CARBON_HOME.`

ERROR:
[image: ERROR_Details]

Even after setting up `CARBON_HOME` in Environment Variable value as `C:\Development_Avecto\WSO2APImServer\ORG\org_wso2am\wso2am-4.1.0` getting same ERROR.

Already checked [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369842/wso2-api-manager-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-enterprise)

Update:
As per below suggestion, i have shorten directory of apim which is mentioned below and updated the same in Environment variable too.

```
C:\Development_Avecto\WSO2APIm\wso2apim-4.1.0\wso2am-4.1.0
```

Any help to resolve this installation issue?

Comment: If you run the `set` command on CMD, do you see the correct `CARBON_HOME` value?

Comment: Hi @RrR-
I set CARBON_HOME in cmd also, when i execute echo %CARBON_HOME% which is giving correct path of apim ie C:\Development_Avecto\WSO2APIm\wso2apim-4.1.0\wso2am-4.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These a few things you can try:

1. Try to run the product from a shorter directory path and long directory pats have issues in Windows OS
2. Check whether JAVA_HOME set properly
3. Run the command prompt with Admin privileges

Please try the above and share your feedback.

Comment: Hi @Joy Rathnayake,
In same system , wso2 EI server is running smoothly in cmd, so i think admin privileges is not the problem. even shorten the directory , same issue happens. when i execute echo %CARBON_HOME% which will give me correct apim path "C:\Development_Avecto\WSO2APIm\wso2apim-4.1.0\wso2am-4.1.0".please suggest some other way if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether you have version.txt file in the <APIM_HOM>/bin directory?

If it is not there, add the file with the content `WSO2 API Manager v4.1.0`.

Comment: Hi @Lakshitha,

version.txt file already available under <APIM_HOM>/bin directory. seems like longer path issue and i have updated my answer too. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion given by @Joy Rathnayake, I have shorten APIm directory and set `CARBON_HOME` in Environment Variable section which resolves my issue.

APIM Directory: `C:\Development_Avecto\WSO2APIm\wso2am-4.1.0\bin`

CARBON_HOME: `C:\Development_Avecto\WSO2APIm\wso2am-4.1.0`

JAVA_HOME: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291`

[image: APIm running]

Now APIm started to run.

Special Thanks to @Joy Rathnayake